# É possível retornar a classe filha através de um método na classe pai?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, herança, genéricos

Estou fazendo um *builder* e gostaria que tivesse o seguinte comportamento:

```
abstract class ClassePaiBuilder
{
    public ClassePaiBuilder SetAtributo(string atributo)
    {
        // codigo
        return this;
    }

    public string Build()
    {
        string result = "";
        //processo os atributos e gero uma string
        return result;
    }
}

class ClasseFilhaBuilder : ClassePaiBuilder
{
    public ClasseFilhaBuilder SetOutroAtributo(string outroAtributo)
    {
        // codigo
        return this;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public void Run()
    {
        string valorQualquer = new ClasseFilhaBuilder()
            .SetAtributo("atributo da classe pai")
            .SetOutroAtributo("atributo da classe filha")
            .Build();
    }
}
```

É possível? Neste caso, a compilação está quebrando porquê no `SetAtributo` estou retornando a instância tipada como `ClassePaiBuilder`, que não possui o método `SetOutroAtributo`.

Comment: Esses `return this` tão certos mesmo? Ou isso foi só pro exemplo?

Comment: Sim @jbueno, estão certos.

Comment: Ok. Mas qual é o objetivo disso? O código em `Run()` não faz sentido.

Comment: O objetivo pode ser qualquer coisa, imagina que no final vou gerar uma string. Editei para tentar melhorar o exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O melhor que eu consegui pensar para não criar uma dependência sem sentido foi isto:

```
abstract class ClassePaiBuilder<T> where T : ClassePaiBuilder<T> {
    public T SetAtributo(string atributo) {
        // codigo
        return (T)(object)this;
    }

    public object Build() {
        return new object();
    }
}

class ClasseFilhaBuilder : ClassePaiBuilder<ClasseFilhaBuilder> {
    public ClasseFilhaBuilder SetOutroAtributo(string outroAtributo) {
        // codigo
        return this;
    }
}

public class Program {
    public void Main() {
        new ClasseFilhaBuilder()
            .SetAtributo("atributo da classe pai")
            .SetOutroAtributo("atributo da classe filha")
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NL6yMW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HGbxEt). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Builder.cs).

O tipo genérico está sendo usado para comunicar a classe pai qual é o tipo que deve ser usado para converter o `this`. E obviamente tem a restrição para permitir apenas tipos derivados dela serem usados na conversão.

Não é uma solução maravilhosa, mas funciona. Pense bem se vale a pena fazer isto.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou :D no meu caso eu criei alguns builders que geram strings, com os mesmos parâmetros, mas com resultados diferentes, inclusive podendo ter outros parâmetros. Nesse caso, eu quis centralizar os parâmetros repetidos.